# Vitest no coverage on TypeScript's types and interfaces

Tags: typescript, code-coverage, vitest

I have a Nuxt3 project with Vite (and Vitest), and in files where I only export types or interfaces, I'm receiving 0% coverage (these are being used in other parts of the project). However, in files that have both actual functionality and types or interfaces defined, I am receiving 100% coverage. Where could the problem be?

Here are the results of the report.
[image: coverage result]

Specifically, the files LogInResponse, LogInRepositoryInterface, and SessionRepositoryInterfaces only export types or interfaces, and they are receiving 0% coverage. However, in the files FetchLogInRepository and StorageSessionRepository, which have both types and interfaces defined and used internally, I am receiving 100% coverage.

Here is my vitest.config.ts file:

```
import path from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    coverage: {
      all: true,
      include: ['Modules/Auth/**/*.ts']
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname)
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the LogInResponse.ts file (0% coverage), which is being used as the return type in a method of LogIn.ts (which has tests and 100% coverage).

```
export type LogInResponse = {
  status: 'ok'
} | {
  status: 'error'
  message: string | null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it by changing the provider from 'c8' to 'istanbul'. To do this, apart from uninstalling 'c8' with the command `yarn remove @vitest/coverage-c8` and installing 'istanbul' with `yarn add @vitest/coverage-istanbul`, I also had to set the value 'istanbul' for the property `test.coverage.provider` in `vitest.config.ts`. Now, the files that only contain types or interfaces no longer appear, and they have also disappeared from the files that had classes or other executable code along with interfaces and types. However, I believe this solution works for me.

Comment: There is a typo on the command to remove **V**8 coverage dependency 
`yarn remove @vitest/coverage-v8`